# How to draw a point over an image in Image(WPF), runtime with event

Tags: c#, wpf, draw

I have the following problem: I'm using `Image` component in WPF. I load my `Image` that is a `map` for me. I want to make a `Button` that if I click on, I will be allowed to click on my `map` and draw a point. That point should be "unique", so it should remember **coordinates/description**(I will store it in a database).
Coordinates should be read only from that image, not from the whole form.
I need `OnMouseClick` event after my point creation.

What should I use/read about to do that ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Canvas allows you to place an object using left/top coordinates.
2. You need to place canvas exactly over the image with same dimensions as image.
3. To accomplish this, you should use a Grid, as it allows controls to stack over each other.
4. You can get the mouse click coordinates using `e.GetPosition()` in `MouseLeftButtonDown` event handler. As canvas is covering up image, so you will get coord according to image.

   ```
   <Grid>
       <Image x:Name="MapImg"  Source="img/map.gif" Stretch="Fill" MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonDown_1"/>
       <Canvas x:Name="Cnv"/>
   </Grid>

    private void Image_MouseLeftButtonDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       {  
           Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();
           ellipse.Fill = Brushes.Sienna;
           ellipse.Width = 100;
           ellipse.Height = 100 ;
           ellipse.StrokeThickness = 2;

           Cnv.Children.Add(ellipse);

           Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, e.GetPosition(MapImg).X);
           Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, e.GetPosition(MapImg).Y);            
       }
   ```

Comment: I just added `GetPosition(canvas)` and it works so good :) Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yep, @Marox comment makes it work. For some reason `e.GetPosition(MapImg)` doesn't work, tough I see it returns same values as `e.GetPosition(Cnv)`. Well, weird WPF I guess